# How to setup detect Data changes in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I have setup detect data changes in power bi for Incremental refresh using lastupdatedDate.For handling deletes,I have setup a flag IsDeleted and update the flag and lastupdateddate everytime a record is deleted in DB.

To remove deleted records in power BI,i have also  filtered remove records where isDeleted=1 in Power Query editor.

Now incremental refresh is setup for 10 days with detect data changes.

Consider for 1 day there are only records which are deleted i.e soft deleted in Db but incremental refresh doesn’t identify this and deleted records remain in power Bi.I guess this is because of the filter isDeleted=1 in power Bi

Can anyone suggest a way to remove soft deleted records in power bi?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a custom query for change data detection.

[Custom Queries For “Detect Data Changes” In Power BI Incremental Refresh](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2022/07/31/custom-queries-for-detect-data-changes-in-power-bi-incremental-refresh/)

Or you can remove the Power Query filter on isDeleted, and add a report-level filter instead.